# CultureInfo and DateTime in ASP.Net Page

Tags: asp.net, datetime

I have a ASP.Net Page with a MSSQL Database.

Here is my code:

```
lblReadTime.Text = pm.Timestamp.ToShortDateString() + " " + pm.Timestamp.ToShortTimeString();
```

Poorly it shows the datetime format in US-format.
How I can get there the german format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64.aspx) overload that allows you to specify the format string and the culture. [The `g` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#GeneralDateShortTime) is a combination of the short date and short time formats:

```
lblReadTime.Text =
    pm.Timestamp.ToString("g", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change it at a global level then you could add the [`globalization`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) element in your web.config:

```
<globalization culture="de-DE" uiCulture="de-DE" />
```